# php session_start() permisson denied

Tags: php5

> PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied

I am getting it in my apache error log

`/var/lib/php5` owner and group is root, so is it fine to change the group to www-data, since its on a production server please help me out

Comment: Already answered in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930870/zend-session-zend-auth-randomly-throws-error-message-ps-files-cleanup-dir-ope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's fine. 
Webserver have to write somewhere sessions files. You can change this path in the php.ini file.